# Синхронизация phpmyadmin на локальном пк

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, apache, phpmyadmin

На пк стоит 2 ОС: wind7 и mint17.3 , На обеих стоит апач2 и phpmyadmin. Задача состоит в том, чтоб работать с одной БД на разных ОС.

Comment: Разве нельзя сделать так, чтобы обе базы смотрели на один и тот же путь в файловой системе? Ведь данные в базе, это (например) папка `data`. Типа в `my.ini` - `datadir` установить один путь

Comment: Ну да, это и нужно, просто я не знаю где этот путь прописывать. Ну и к тому же файловая система у разделов под ОС разная.

Answer (score 2):

Для работы c ext в windows можно воспользоваться программой [Ext2Fsd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/files/Ext2fsd/). А чтение/запись ntfs делается штатными средствами linux